# pull all text between [ ] with powershell

Tags: regex, powershell-4.0

I have multiple strings that contain names with  [ ] inside of them. For example:

`"Tim Drake [Van Dyke]"
 "Alex Scott [Hammer Field]"`

I need to pull the "Van Dyke" out. So far the only thing I have successfully done is to remove the [] characters.

```
$Test = "Time Drake [Van Dyke]"    
$Test -replace "[\[\]]",''
```

Any suggestions so far?

Comment: You should look into regular expressions

Comment: If your input text is as structured as with your example then consider using `-split`. At every step, you need to identify you delimiter, split and then repeat the process on the proper fragment until it is good enough to e.g. just clean/strip the quotes.